# Fastest way to change column type from varchar2 to number on large table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table which contains a VARCHAR2 column that must me changed into NUMBER.

**The table contains more than 30 millions rows.**

The table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE EFF (
    MOD         VARCHAR2(6)     NOT NULL,
    MP          VARCHAR2(6)     NOT NULL,
    PROG        VARCHAR2(1)     NOT NULL,
    RNK         VARCHAR2(4)     NOT NULL,
    EFF_STS     VARCHAR2(1),
    EFF_PART    VARCHAR2(1),
    CONSTRAINT PK_EFF PRIMARY KEY (MOD, MP, PROG, RNK)
);
```

The code I used on Oracle 11g to change the `RNK` column type :

```
ALTER TABLE EFF ADD (NRNK NUMBER(5));
UPDATE EFF SET NRNK = TO_NUMBER(RNK);
ALTER TABLE EFF MODIFY (NRNK NUMBER(5) NOT NULL);
```

Then I would modify the primary key and drop the old column :

```
ALTER TABLE EFF DROP PRIMARY KEY DROP INDEX;
ALTER TABLE EFF ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EFF PRIMARY KEY (MOD, MP, PROG, NRNK);
ALTER TABLE EFF DROP COLUMN RNK;
```

The **UPDATE** phase is very long, at least 20 minutes.
What could be the best way to do it faster ?

There is no indexes other than the primary key.

Comment: What is the matter? Do you want to perform this task constantly? If so you have big problems with your app's architecture.

Comment: @zaratustra The app **had** bad architecture, and this is to correct it (it's a very old app)

Comment: I guess you don't have to improve the performance, because your users won't use this feature, will they?

Comment: If this correction has to be done only once, 20 minutes seems ok to me. Why do you need to make it faster?

Comment: You could try putting the data into another table, altering the existing table, and re-inserting it.  However, copying the table twice might take as long or longer.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt It's a small part of a whole database/application update, and we would avoid long service interruption because the application has to be stopped during this procedure.

Comment: @kev you don't have to finish this task at once, you can perform it step-by-step

Comment: @kev Why do you have to stop the application during this procedure?

Comment: Yes another solution could be to do it step by step, but is doesn't answer to my question, to know if there is a way to do it faster  (PL/SQL...). 
The maintenance team has to stop and deploy the new webapp behind (in accordance to the new DB schema). It's not up to me...

Comment: Have you tried locking the table exclusively before the update statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, you can use parallel operations:

**Parallel DML**

Let your table support parallel operations:

```
ALTER TABLE EFF parallel;
```

Then you perform all your steps as you describe in the question.

**Parallel DDL + CTAS**

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table_EFF
PARALLEL
AS
SELECT MOD, MP, PROG, TO_NUMBER(RNK), EFF_PART
  FROM EFF
```

Then you drop your table:

```
DROP TABLE EFF;
```

Then you rename your temp table:

```
ALTER TABLE temp_table_EFF RENAME TO EFF;
```

Then you add indexes for to this new table:

```
ALTER TABLE EFF ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EFF PRIMARY KEY (MOD, MP, PROG, NRNK);
```

I have no tables with 30M records, so I can't tell you what method is faster. Try both. If you think that there won't be decent performance improvement try to use the `NOLOGGING` option to forbid your table generate the redo information.

Comment: It took about 30 seconds with your solution, nice optimization ! Thanks a lot :)
Did not try with `NOLOGGING`.

Comment: Tell me what solution is faster please

Comment: Parallel DDL + CTAS is the fastest.
There was no significant change with parallel DML.